# BeautifulSoup: Select div from nested section and div elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

how can I extract the div['field-item'] content which is child of a section with class "field-name-field-mpd-total-capacity" ? I'm working on https://rbnenergy.com/node/6081 for reference.

```
<section class="field-name-field-mpd-total-capacity">
    <h2 class="field-label">Total Capacity:&nbsp;</h2>
    <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item even">125 Mb/d</div>
    </div>
</section>
</td>
```

Maybe it's too late for a brainwave at me. Here is my example code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
    <section class="field-name-field-mpd-total-capacity"><h2 class="field-label">Total Capacity:&nbsp;</h2><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even">125 Mb/d</div></div></section>          </td>
    """
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
out = soup.find("section", { "class" : "field-item" })
print(out)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
    <section class="field-name-field-mpd-total-capacity"><h2 class="field-label">Total Capacity:&nbsp;</h2><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even">125 Mb/d</div></div></section>          </td>
    """

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
for allz in soup.findAll("section", { "class" : "field-name-field-mpd-total-capacity" }):
    print(allz.find("div", { "class" : "field-item"}).string)
```

It will also work directly from the web source. Use something like

`page = requests.get("https://example.com/node/")` for it

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> html = """
...     <section class="field-name-field-mpd-total-capacity"><h2 class="field-label">Total Capacity:&nbsp;</h2><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item     even">125 Mb/d</div></div></section>          </td>
...     """
>>>
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
>>> out = soup.find("div", { "class" : "field-item" })
>>> print(out)
<div class="field-item even">125 Mb/d</div>
>>> out.text
'125 Mb/d'
```

The first argument of `find` is ([*usually*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kinds-of-filters)) the name of the element to be found. It will fail on the provided example because there is no `section` element with the specific class. You can change it to `div` to achieve the desired result.

To extract data items from `section` with the class `field-name-field-mpd-total-capacity` elements you can use:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>
>>> html = '''<section class="field-name-field-mpd-total-capacity"><h2 class="field-label">Total Capacity:&nbsp;</h2><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even">125 Mb/d</div></div></section>          </td>'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
>>> section = soup.find('section', {'class': 'field-name-field-mpd-total-capacity'})
>>> [x.text for x in section.find_all('div', {'class': 'field-item'})]
['125 Mb/d']
```

Personally I found it very useful to transform the pages I am scraping into dicts for easier handling. Based on the page you provided I think this may help you:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://rbnenergy.com/node/6081')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

data = {}

for element in soup.find_all("section", { "class" : "field" }):
    key = element.find('h2', {'class': 'field-label'})
    content = element.find('div', {'class': 'field-items'}).text

    data[key.text.rstrip(':\xa0')] = content

print(data)
```

Sample output:

```
{'Operator': 'Rangeland', 'Commodity': 'Crude Oil', 'Stage': 'Operational', 'Project Type': 'New Build', 'In Service Date': 'Q3/2016', 'Diameter': '12 inches', 'Length': '109 miles', 'Base Capacity': '125 Mb/d', 'Total Capacity': '125 Mb/d', 'Origin': 'Orla, TXUnited States', 'Destination': 'Midland, TXUnited States'}
```

Comment: Oh thanks. But the parent class must be "field-name-field-mpd-total-capacity" because instead other field-item's would be found.

Comment: No problem! :). Is it there one list? If that's the case you could use `find_all` which finds all the matching elements instead of `find`, which only finds the first matching element. Anyway, I'll check the website you provided to try and provide a better answer.

Comment: content = element.find('div', {'class': 'field-items'}).text has no attribute 'text' at my Python.

Comment: Which version of python / BeautifulSoup are you using?